# PHP - Combine 2 elements from the same 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, web, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I want to combine the two elements into one but my problem is i don't know how the logic works. here's my code:

1. queries for retrieving data from MySQL Database **(where the DATA came from)**:

   ```
   $Retrieve_Answers = "SELECT * FROM Answers";
   $Result_Answers = mysqli_query($Connection, $Retrieve_Answers);
   ```
2. Declaration of array storage for the data:

   `$points = array();`
3. Retrieval process of data from MySql database

   `if(mysqli_num_rows($Result_Answers) > 0){
       while($Retrieved_Data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result_Answers)){
           $points[] = $Retrieved_Data;
       }
   }`
4. Printing of data from the $points array

   `echo "These are the $TotalDataPoints data points: ";
   foreach($points as $point){
       echo "[";
       echo $point['Answer_Data'];
       echo "], ";
   }
   echo "";`

**OUTPUT: **

**[80], [55],** [86], [59], [19], [85], [41], [47], [57], [58], [76], [22], [94], [60], [13], [93], [90], [48], [52], [54], [62], [46], [88], [44], [85], [24], [63], [14], [51], [40], [75], [31], [86], [62], [81], [95], [47], [22], [43], [95], [71], [19], [17], [65], [69], [21], [59], [60], [59], [12], [15], [22], [49], [93], [56], [35], [18], [20], [39], [59], [50], [15], [10], [47], [75], [18], [13], [45], [30], [62], [95], [79], [64], [11], [92], [14], [94], [49], [39], [13], [60], [68], [62], [10], [74], [44], [37], [42], [97], [60], [47], [73],

**Objective / Goal:**

What I want to achieve is to combine two elements from an array into.

Example, from the output above the first two elements output is **[80], [55],** right? what I want to happen is become [80, 55].

**Questions: How to achieve that goal? and what are the logic for that?**

P.S. I'm doing this for my KMeans Clustering algorithm.

Comment: It looks to me from your code that you are getting from the server an array where each element contains an array of length 1.  Is that correct?

Do you want the output to be `[80,55],[86,59],....` or `[80,55,86,59,...]`?

Comment: I want the output to be [80,55],[86,59], and so on.. yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to achieve your expected result.

### 1. If your expectation is to display the values immediately

> With minimum changes in **Step 4**

```
<?php
// Number of elements you want to keep.
$numberOfElements = 2;
echo "These are the $TotalDataPoints data points: ";
foreach($points as $i => $point) {
  if ($i % $numberOfElements === 0) {
    echo "[";
  }
  echo $point['Answer_Data'];
  if ($i % $numberOfElements === $numberOfElements - 1) {
    echo "], ";        
  } else {
    echo ",";
  }
}
?>
```

---

### 2. If your expectation is to store values in that format to perform some other operation, change as below

> **Step 3** as below

```
<?php
// Number of elements you want to keep.
$numberOfElements = 2;
$tmp = [];
if (mysqli_num_rows($Result_Answers) > 0) {
  while($Retrieved_Data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result_Answers)){
    $tmp[] = $Retrieved_Data['Answer_Data'];

    if (count($tmp) === $numberOfElements) {
      $points[] = $tmp;
      $tmp = [];
    }
  }
}
?>
```

> **Step 4** as below

```
<?php
foreach($points as $point) {
  echo '[' . implode(', ', $point) . ']';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without taking away from Somnath Sinha's answer you could also try the [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) method.  This replacement for Step 3 of Sinha's feels cleaner to me.

```
<?php
// Number of elements you want to keep.
$numberOfElements = 2;

if (mysqli_num_rows($Result_Answers) > 0) {
  while($Retrieved_Data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result_Answers)){
    $points[] = $Retrieved_Data['Answer_Data'][0];    
  }
}
$points = array_chunk($points,$numberofElements);
?>
```